# Key press event not registered properly by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with some image data where it is helpful to click on different elements in the image.  I would like to have "shift-click" be the triggering mechanism for registering the cursor position.

I wrote a "click" function which does the right thing.  However, when I tried to upgrade it to "shift-click" it simply does not work.  The weird thing is that it DOES work on my coworker's computer using an older version of Matplotlib (1.1, running on a linux box, where mine is 1.4.2, running on a Mac.  Both are running Python 2.7)

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  I'm completely out of ideas.  Other possibly relevant info is I installed Seaborn recently (and then uninstalled it) and upgraded matplotlib (and tried to downgrade, but that failed)

**EDIT** OK, I think I understand now.  Shift must be pressed and released at least once before starting to work properly.  Maybe there is a workaround to this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def shiftclick(refimage, comment=None, eq=True):
    class EventHandler:
        def __init__(self, spotlist):
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', self.on_key_release)
            self.shift_is_held = False
        def on_key_press(self, event):
            if event.key == 'shift':
               self.shift_is_held = True
        def on_key_release(self, event):
            if event.key == 'shift':
               self.shift_is_held = False
        def onpress(self, event):
            if event.inaxes!=ax:
                return
            if self.shift_is_held:
                xi, yi = (int(round(n)) for n in (event.xdata, event.ydata))
                value = im.get_array()[xi,yi]
                print xi, yi
                spotlist.append((xi, yi))
    im = plt.imshow(refimage, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')

    plt.title('SHIFT-click on locations')
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = plt.gca()

    spotlist = []
    handler=EventHandler(spotlist)
    plt.show()
    return spotlist


def click(refimage, comment=None):
    class EventHandler:
        def __init__(self, spotlist):
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)
        def onpress(self, event):
            if event.inaxes!=ax:
                return
            xi, yi = (int(round(n)) for n in (event.xdata, event.ydata))
            value = im.get_array()[xi,yi]
            print xi, yi
            spotlist.append((xi, yi))
    im = plt.imshow(refimage, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')

    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = plt.gca()

    spotlist = []
    handler=EventHandler(spotlist)
    plt.show()
    return spotlist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.random.random((100, 100))
    #this works
    click(a)
    #this doesn't work
    shiftclick(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here was the problem.  After upgrading Matplotlib, the MacOSX backend refused to deal with event handling properly.  It ignored all shift-button presses.

Using the TKAgg backend fixed the problem, as long as shift is pressed at least once before trying to select points.  This is still undesirable.

Using the Qt4Agg backend had the best possible behavior.  As long as the window was selected, it responded to the first shift press correctly.